# Old value of the column not reflected in triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

my update trigger is as below .

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tb_sample_UpdationTrigger] on [dbo].[tb_sample]  for UPDATE
as
 if UPDATE(R_Id) 
 insert into dbo.test_log(Attribute,Action,OldValue,NEwValue,UserId,ModifiedDate)   

(SELECT 'R_Id','update',tb_sample.R_Id,inserted.R_Id ,1,GETDATE()
 from inserted 
 inner join tb_sample on inserted.id =tb_sample.id)
```

. I update the R_Id from 100000 to 200000 . But record inserted to the log table is

```
   R_Id update  200000      200000      1   2012-01-20 12:38:16.730
```

If we see the old value and new value both are 200000 . 
Wats wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the old value you have to use the `deleted` special table, since an update can be seen as a delete and an insert action. See: [Using the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx). So your select should look like (untested):

```
SELECT 'R_Id','update', d.R_Id, i.R_Id ,1,GETDATE()
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.id=i.id
INNER JOIN tb_sample ON tb_sample.id=i.id
```